# What is the best practice to save a product by its id ? Using factory or repository?

Tags: magento2, product, catalog

Save product by its id in magento 2.
What is the best practice in use ?

Answer (score 1):

**Repository** is the best way to save the product. Because of  `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::save()` has future, in future will be more use where `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::save()` will fully deprecated in near future.

Comment: Thankyou for sharing the knowledge :)